# Phrase, idiom, or expression for putting forward one's own requirement by saying that it comes from someone else

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Context

My boss one day called me into his office and said that I now had to include tasks 3, 5, and 6 to complete the entire assignment. Traditionally, the usual sequence of task was from 1 through 10, but management had stopped 3, 5 and 6 many years ago.

The boss said it is management that has instructed this, but he does not know that I am in the panel to make amendments to the procedure if anything is pushed for a change. Thus this is his own quirkiness that he wants to impose this additional requirement in the name of management (without their approval). So I want to know what is the phrase, idiom, or expression appropriate for putting his own requirement by saying that it is management's instruction.

I feel this would count as duplicate, but I tried searching for this and really couldn't ascertain whether alternative word like *name dropping* completes my requirement particularly (it could but I have no way to ascertain). So I will leave it to the expertise of others.

Comment: Name dropping doesn't cover this.

Comment: In negotiating it is often happens that "boss" puts the decision making power in a *higher authority*. This is done by saying "It's my boss who made the requirements, not me." Or "I understand your concerns. I will take it up at the next sales meeting." This is why before you ever start to bargain you make sure the one you are talking to has the power to make these decisions. Otherwise they can surprise you with these dodges. "Don't look at me!" This is not a language construct, just workplace advice. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

An expression for disclaiming responsibility is "*passing the buck*". *Collins Cobuild* defines this as:

> If you pass the buck, you refuse to accept responsibility for
> something, and say that someone else is responsible.
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-pass-the-buck

*Dictionary.com* has this:

> To shift blame from oneself to another person: “Passing the buck is a
> way of life in large bureaucracies.” (See the buck stops here.)
>
> https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pass--the--buck

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of ***misrepresentation***.

ODO:

> **[misrepresentation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misrepresentation)**
>   *NOUN* [mass noun]
>   The action or offence of giving a false or misleading account of the nature of something.
>
> ‘In many cases consent was obtained by Government officials through
>   fraud, coercion or misrepresentation, tactics which annulled the
>   validity of such consent.’

Answer (score 0):

One word for this would be ***self-serving***:

> [**self-serving**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-serving) (adjective):
>   serving one's own interests often in disregard of the truth or the interests of others
>
> ***Synonyms:***
>    egocentric, egoistic (also egoistical), egomaniacal, egotistic (or egotistical), narcissistic, self-absorbed, self-centered, self-concerned, self-infatuated, self-interested, self-involved, self-loving, self-obsessed, self-oriented, self-preoccupied, self-regarding, self-seeking, selfish, solipsistic